# Displaying bold text from SQLite in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite, uikit, uitableview

We're storing text in `SQLite` and displaying it in `UITableViewCell` within our iPhone application.  `UITableViewCell` seems to recognize line breaks from `SQLite`, but not bold text.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your storing the entire string in a label (or similar construct, you can't control bold, italics etc). You can do it as two labels, where the first label say is bold and the second is not. Then you load the bolded text in the first label and the remainder of the string in the second. Make sense?

You can style the entire label programmatically, but you cannot apply bold to parts of the label's string.